# Linux script to read a file and copy contents at specific location of other file

Tags: xml, bash, shell

In this scenario there are 2 inputs:

1. Main data file (`tab-separated txt`)
2. Template file

Main data `txt` file looks like this

```
abc paris
xyz london
jkl dubai
```

The requirement here is to get an output file as Template filled with data from the Main data file.

```
inputdir="/home/InputFile"
for line in $(cat $inputdir/$1)
do
content=${line}
name=$(echo $content|awk -F'\t' '{print $1}')
place=$(echo $content|awk -F'\t' '{print $2}')
echo "$name"
echo "$place"
done
```

Kindly suggest the best way to complete it and copy this contents to output file will be `XML`, which would look like this:

```
<ROOT>
    <FileHeader>
        <name>abc</name> --this_is input of contents copied from above script
    </FileHeader>
    <FileDetail>
        <place>paris</place> --this_is input of contents copied from above script
    </FileDetail>

    <FileHeader>
        <name>xyz</name>
    </FileHeader>
    <FileDetail>
        <place>london</place>
    </FileDetail>

    <FileHeader>
        <name>jkl</name>
    </FileHeader>
    <FileDetail>
        <place>dubai</place>
    </FileDetail>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: Where do `$name` and `$place` come from? It is not quite clear. Are you trying to manipulate the content of XML from shell script here?

Comment: Can you show how the tab-separated file looks like?

Comment: @Inian I've edited the content. Yes I'm trying to manipulate the xml content from shell script

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                      

while read line; do                                                      
    word1=$(sed "s/^\(\S*\).*/\1/" <<< "$line")                          
    word2=$(sed "s/.*\s\(\S.*\)$/\1/" <<< "$line")                       
    sed -i'' "0,/<name></s/<name></<name>$word1</" outputfile            
    sed -i'' "0,/<place></s/<place></<place>$word2</" outputfile         
done < inputfile
```

Here `inputfile` contains a list of words separated by spaces or tabs:

```
abc paris
xyz london
jkl dubai
```

and `outputfile` initially is:

```
<ROOT>                                                                   
    <FileHeader>                                                         
        <name></name>                                                       
    </FileHeader>                                                        
    <FileDetail>                                                         
        <place></place>                                                     
    </FileDetail>                                                        

    <FileHeader>                                                         
        <name></name>                                                    
    </FileHeader>                                                        
    <FileDetail>                                                         
        <place></place>                                                  
    </FileDetail>                                                        

    <FileHeader>                                                         
        <name></name>                                                    
    </FileHeader>                                                        
    <FileDetail>                                                         
        <place></place>                                                  
    </FileDetail>                                                        
</ROOT>
```

After running the script, `outputfile` becomes:

```
<ROOT>                                                                      
    <FileHeader>                                                            
        <name>abc</name>                                                    
    </FileHeader>                                                           
    <FileDetail>                                                            
        <place>paris</place>                                                
    </FileDetail>                                                           

    <FileHeader>                                                            
        <name>xyz</name>                                                    
    </FileHeader>                                                           
    <FileDetail>                                                            
        <place>london</place>                                               
    </FileDetail>                                                           

    <FileHeader>                                                            
        <name>jkl</name>                                                    
    </FileHeader>                                                           
    <FileDetail>                                                            
        <place>dubai</place>                                                
    </FileDetail>                                                           
</ROOT>
```

Comment: Above script is printing only the first and the last word, can we read multiple tab separated values and print same way like in above script??